# Statistical test to compare teachers of students taking tests

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multilevel-analysis, proportion

Suppose I have two teachers $T_1$ and $T_2$, who teach students $S_{11}, S_{12}, \dots S_{1n}$ and $S_{21}, S_{22}, \dots S_{2n}$ who then answer questions $Q_1, \dots Q_m$, giving us two $n \times m$ matrices of whether answers are correct not, $A_1$ and $A_2$

I want to work out if $T_1$ is better at preparing students for tests than $T_2$ (assuming lots of things are independent). Note that the rows and column on $A$ are not independent because they are either answers from the same student, or answers to the same question.

I am not interested in reducing variance through testing students before and after.

What statistical tests can I use? And are these the "best possible tests" in the sense that they are not throwing away information (I guess I mean are they [uniformly most powerful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformly_most_powerful_test)

## Potentially related questions

- [Hierarchical / multilevel proportions test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/486590/hierarchical-multilevel-proportions-test)

Answer (score 1):

Given your objective, the most direct (and simplest) analysis would be
to find each student's score  $X_{ij}, i = 1,2; j=1, \dots, n$ (number correct on each student's test.) Then do a Welch two-sample t test to see
if the means $\bar X_1$ and $\bar X_2$ are significantly different.
This assumes that student's average scores are approximately normal.

More complicated designs might provide the opportunity to see if
some specific questions differ from each other or as to preparation by the two teachers. However, I would want to look to see whether the residuals for the ANOVA model are normal.
When fewer items are averaged, the normality assumptions seems
less certain.

**Addendum per Comments on Normality.** Suppose tests
consist of 20 multiple-choice questions each (with scores that can be modeled as binomial), and that
there are 45 students in Class 1 and 55 in Class 2. Then
results might be similar to simulated results below.  Using R.

```
set.seed(2021)  # for reproducibility
x1 = rbinom(45, 20, .73)      # 45 scores in Class 1
summary(x1); length(x1); sd(x1)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  10.00   12.00   14.00   13.78   15.00   18.00 
[1] 45        # sample size
[1] 2.032563  # sample SD
shapiro.test(x1)

        Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  x1
W = 0.95987, p-value = 0.1208  # pass as if normal

x2 = rbinom(55, 20, .75)
summary(x2); length(x2); sd(x2)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  10.00   14.00   15.00   15.05   16.50   19.00 
[1] 55
[1] 2.067546
shapiro.test(x2)

        Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  x2
W = 0.96299, p-value = 0.08851   # pass as if normal
```

The boxplot (left panel) shows no marked skewness or far outliers in scores for either class. Normal probability plots (center and right) are close to linear, indicating near normality

[image]

R code for figure:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
 boxplot(x1, x2, col="skyblue2")
 qqnorm(x1);  qqline(x1, col="blue")
 qqnorm(x2);  qqline(x2, col="blue")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

A Welch 2-sample t test shows a highly significant difference
(P-value $0.003 < 0.05 < 5\%)$ between class average scores (13.8 and 15.1 correct out of 20).

However, it is worthwhile considering whether an average
difference of just a little more than one question per test
is meaningful in terms of the capabilities of the instructors
of the two classes.

```
t.test(x1, x2)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x1 and x2
t = -3.1009, df = 94.72, p-value = 0.002542
alternative hypothesis: 
 true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -2.0942057 -0.4593297
sample estimates:
 mean of x mean of y 
  13.77778  15.05455
```

*Note:* If you still had reservations that data `x1` and `x2` can be taken as if normal, a nonparametric two-sample Wilcoxon Rank Sum test gives a similar P-value.

Comment: Thanks. In this there is an assumption that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are normal, which is going to be true asymptotically presumably. Can I tell when this assumption is valid and how invalid it might be.

For [binomial distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) which are kind of related to this you can get exact confidence intervals and there is an [exact hypothesis test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_test). I guess this isn't possible with the additional complexity?

Comment: (1) If the $\bar X_1$s and $\bar X_2$s don't have extreme outliers, you could assume they are OK. (2) You could make normal probability plots (Q-Q plots) of the $n$ means $\bar X_1,$ and similarly for the means $\bar X_2.$ Both plots should be roughly linear. (3) You could do Shapiro-Wilk tests on both sets of means. (4) You could post them here and ask. // If these are based on tests as described, I anticipate no difficulty. (Scores _could_ be binomial, but I can't be sure of that without looking at your data.)

Comment: See addendum for simulated data illustrating one possible scenario.